# Why was Netsuke written on Ochako's Christmas present?

Tags: my-hero-academia

On Boku no Hero Academia Episode 13, Ochako receives an All Might strap which Netsuke is written on. Since then she keeps it with her all the time.

But why is Netsuke written on it and why does Ochako keep it all the time?

Comment: Possibly related, while it doesn't answer why: [*Netsuke*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netsuke)

Comment: So Ochako's present was a small bagh that could be hanged of kimono. If that was rt he case assuming that present comes from Midoriya why Midoriya would give a Netsuke as present?

Comment: I guess that's also a question that might be hard to find the answers...